# Bloquear un botón si un input está vacío

Tags: javascript, html

estoy tratando de bloquear un botón si un input está vacío cuando se selecciona cierta opcion de un select

Me explico: Tengo un select con 3 opciones las cuales son pendiente, aprobado, rechazado. cuando se selecciona aprobado sale un input en el cual debo ingresar un valor numero pero si ese input esta vacío se debe bloquear el boton pero si selecciona cualquier otra opción de el select se habilita

Codigo

```
<div>
    <label for="status">Estado del proceso</label>
    <select name="status" id="status" onChange="statuses()">
        <option value="pendiente">Pendiente</option>
        <option value="aprobado">Aprobado</option>
        <option value="rechazado">Rechazado</option>
    </select>                    
</div>
<div id="honorary" style="display:none;">
        <input type="number" name="honorary" id="fee">
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Editar" id="update" class="btn btn-success" >
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function statuses() {
        var x = document.getElementById("status").value;
        if ( x == 'aprobado') {
            document.getElementById("honorary").style.display = "";                    
        }else{
            document.getElementById("honorary").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("update").disabled = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Básicamente, lo que no quieres que suceda es que el select tenga el valor de aprobado y se haga click en el botón de update con el nuevo input vacío?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es que, una vez seleccionado el botón de aprobado y el input con id 'fee' no tenga valor, se deshabilite, necesitarías lo siguiente:

Por una parte, en tu **código HTML**, necesitarías añadir la propiedad `onchange` al input `#fee`, de tal formar que pudieses capturar el evento cuando su valor cambie:

```
<div>
    <label for="status">Estado del proceso</label>
    <select name="status" id="status" onChange="statuses()">
        <option value="pendiente">Pendiente</option>
        <option value="aprobado">Aprobado</option>
        <option value="rechazado">Rechazado</option>
    </select>                    
</div>
<div id="honorary" style="display:none;">
        <input type="number" name="honorary" id="fee" onchange="disableUpdateIfFeeIsEmpty()">
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Editar" id="update" class="btn btn-success" >
```

Por otra parte, en tu código **Javascript**, necesitarías una función que te evaluase si el input `#fee` contiene algún valor y, **habilitar o deshabilitar** el botón de `#update`:

```
function statuses() {
  var x = document.getElementById("status").value;
  if ( x == 'aprobado') {
    document.getElementById("honorary").style.display = "";

    disableUpdateIfFeeIsEmpty();
  }else{
    document.getElementById("honorary").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("update").disabled = false;
  }
}

function disableUpdateIfFeeIsEmpty()
{
  if (document.getElementById("fee").value == '') {
    document.getElementById("update").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("update").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 1):

**Parte 0**

- Moví el listener por fuera del código HTML y al asignarlo a una variable podemos vigilar el evento `change`
- Cada que dicho evento ocurre podemos obtener y asignar a una variable el `value` que cada etiqueta `option` contiene y que nos servirá para hacer el filtrado y lógica posterior

**Parte 1**

- Mediante condicionales establecemos primero si el valor tomado del `select` corresponde a aprobado entonces:

  - Mostramos el div que contiene el input cambiando su propiedad a block, esto lo logramos mediante la variable con la cual lo recuperamos
  - Verificamos si el input que obtenemos por su id esta vacio entonces deshabilitamos el `input` con su propiedad `disabled`
- En caso de que la condición principal al inicio del punto anterior no se cumpla, entonces:

  - Volvemos a ocultar el `div` que contiene al botón
  - Volvemos a habilitar el botón cambiando su propiedad disabled a false

Código

```html
    <div>
        <label for="status">Estado del proceso</label>
        <select name="status" id="status">
            <option value="pendiente">Pendiente</option>
            <option value="aprobado">Aprobado</option>
            <option value="rechazado">Rechazado</option>
        </select>                    
    </div>
    <div id="honorary" style="display:none;">
            <input type="number" name="honorary" id="fee">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Editar" id="update" class="btn btn-success" >
    
    <script>
      let opcionSeleccionada = document.getElementById("status")
      let boton = document.getElementById("update")
      let botonOculto = document.getElementById("honorary")
      let cajaTexto = document.getElementById("fee")
      
      opcionSeleccionada.addEventListener("change", () => {
        let seleccion = opcionSeleccionada.options[opcionSeleccionada.selectedIndex].value
        
        if (seleccion === "aprobado") {  
          botonOculto.style.display = "block"
          if(cajaTexto.value === "") {
            boton.disabled = true
          } 
        } else {
          botonOculto.style.display = "none"
          boton.disabled = false
        }
      })
    </script>
```

> Como pequeño consejo, no mezcles el código JS directo en el HTML sería mas conveniente agregar acciones a las etiquetas recuperando estas por medio de sus id o clases y asignandolo a variables.

Answer (score 1):

De inicios tu boton debería estar deshabilitado:

```
<input type="submit" value="Editar" id="update" class="btn btn-success" disabled>
```

Y luego puedes hacer esto:

```
const fee = document.getElementById("fee");
const boton = document.getElementById("update");

function statuses(){
     //Sigue igual tu código aquí
}

function disableIfNotAble(e){
     if(e.currentTarget.value == ""){
        boton.disabled = true;
     }else boton.disabled = false;
}

fee.addEventListener("input", e => disableIfNotAble(e));
```

Puedes deshabilitar un boton usando el atributo disabled, entonces en pocas palabras lo que se hace ahí es extraer los elementos que nos interesan, añadirle un evento oyente a nestro input, el evento oyente es de tipo input (se ejecuta cada vez que el valor del input cambia), entonces, en la función disableIfNotAble lo que se hace es comprobar si el input tiene contenido, si lo tiene colocamos el disabled en false, pero si no, bloqueamos el boton, colocando el disabled en true.