# Deshabilitar botón submit cuando cumpla unas condiciones

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy teniendo problemas, necesito que el botón submit esté deshabilitado cuando venga por defecto el campo Estado = Contestado. Lo que me pasa es que solo sucede esto si escribo a mano "Contestado", no cuando viene por defecto. Mi código es este pero no lo estoy consiguiendo.
Gracias

```html
<input name="Estado" id="fe696" value="Contestado" onkeyup="comprobar()"/>

<input  type="submit" value="Enviar respuestas" id="fe583">

<script>
    function comprobar() {
        if (this.value != 'Contestado'){
            var Pagar = document.getElementById("fe583");
            Pagar.disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Bloquear un botón si un input está vacío](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/346485/bloquear-un-bot%c3%b3n-si-un-input-est%c3%a1-vac%c3%ado)

Comment: @MauricioContreras muchas gracias, no me sirve porque lo que me enseñas sucede cuando hay un onchange. A mi me pasa que el valor "contestado" en el campo estado vendrá por defecto en el código (de hecho, es un campo oculto que no se podrá ni modificar). Se le ocurre alguna forma? Mil gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente tenés que llamar a la función comprobar() cuando se carga la página (cuando levanta el default), y para ello, referenciar el value del objeto por id:

```
<input name="Estado" id="fe696" value="Contestado" onkeyup="comprobar()"/>
<input  type="submit" value="Enviar respuestas" id="fe583">

<script>
    comprobar();

    function comprobar() {
        $("#fe583").attr("disabled",$("#fe696").val()==='Contestado');
    }
</script>
```

Te cambié la función para que levante por id, en vez de this.value. Y usé jquery en vez de vanilla, ya que vi que agregaste como tag jquery.